# How to download and install libicu55 package for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: couchdb

How to download and install libicu55 package for Ubuntu 18.04?

I ran the command `sudo apt-get install couchdb -y` then following list appeared.

[image: libicu55]

Comment: Where you got `couchdb` package? Please add output of `apt-cache policy couchdb` to the question.

Comment: Please copy and paste those texts from the image...

Comment: Candidate: 2.2.0~xenial
 2.2.0~xenial 500 500 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb xenial/main amd64
2.2.0~bionic 500 500 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb bionic/main amd64 
2.1.2~xenial 500 500 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb xenial/main amd64 
2.1.2~bionic 500 500 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb bionic/main amd64 2.1.1-1~xenial 500 500 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb xenial/main amd64 
 2.1.0~xenial 500 500 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb xenial/main amd64 
     2.0.0~xenial 500
        500 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb xenial/main amd64

Answer (score 19):

libicu55 was supported until Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial, but it is compatible with 18.04 Bionic as well.

Add the following repository and install the package

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libicu55
```

Comment: This helped me with installation of .NET Core on WSL Ubuntu

Comment: And for me it helped me with installing PowerShell. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can install the .deb package manually:

```
sudo wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb -P /tmp/
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb
```